# How to create a grouped and stacked bar chart with overlapping data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have data showing me how many objects are of specific type and how many object are of specific multiple types like this:

1. Set A

   - Type A: 30
   - Type B: 16
   - Type C: 180
   - Type D: 119
   - Type E: 20
   - Type D and E at the same time: 18
   - Type C and D and E at the same time: 2
2. Set B

   - Type A: 10
   - Type B: 14
   - Type C: 0
   - Type D: 99
   - Type E: 18
   - Type D and E at the same time: 18
   - Type C and D and E at the same time: 2

And I want to show it on bar chart such way that you could easily tell how many objects are of each type and how many have multiple at the same time.

Something like this (don't mind the scale for Set B):
[image: chart]

It doesn't matter what Python library you use, I just want the chart to be on image or it could also be something like in plotly - html interactive format.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **Stacked barplot** with `matplotlib` library, [check this](https://python-graph-gallery.com/12-stacked-barplot-with-matplotlib/).

Or you can do it with `seaborn`, something like:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
dataframe.set_index('Set').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: But what about moving left and right chart up + dividing the left one into two pieces?

Comment: Also I'm not sure what do I need to do with that code for `seaborn`

Comment: Can you post some code, what have you tried by now?